# Merging switch config in Notepad ++ Tips

Tags: networking, python, notepad++, script

The document and config is much bigger than this but for example.. I have the config all documented out in excel and I want an easy way to transfer this config to the switch without going back and forth copy paste scroll, etc.

So in notepad I can copy and paste but I need a way (if there is one) to merge the config together.. for example:

(There are a lot more vlans per trunk, just shortened it to make it easier to read)... so essentially I have 100 + LAG interfaces.. and then 100 + trunk configs I need to make to the switch..

Is there a way to merge these together automated so it reads like the second example instead?

Example 1:


interface lag 38 multi-chassis

interface lag 39 multi-chassis

interface lag 40 multi-chassis


vlan trunk allowed 1,100,170

vlan trunk allowed 1,100,170,207

vlan trunk allowed 1,100,207,999-1000

----------------------------------------------------------------------

Example 2(What i need):

interface lag 38 multi-chassis

vlan trunk allowed 1,100,170


interface lag 39 multi-chassis

vlan trunk allowed 1,100,170,207


interface lag 40 multi-chassis

vlan trunk allowed 1,100,207,999-1000


Its quick for 3 but for 100 + on multiple switches its a daunting task.. any help appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Given the pattern will be the same (go to end of line 1, new line, go to line vlan line, cut line, go to empty line, paste line), you're probably best recording a macro of you doing this manually for 3 examples, then play it for 1 or 2 more iterations. If it's working as expected, run the macro to the end of the file.

Comment: Or you could put the `interface` lines into column A, and the `vlan` lines in column B in an Excel sheet, concatenate the data into column C (a,",", b) then paste it into Notepad++ and replace the `,` with a carriage return/line feed. This is probably more reliable than a macro.

Comment: @spikey_richie I like that idea.. thank you good sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the two lists into 2 columns in Excel. Then use `concatenate` to join each pair into a string, separated by a `;`

[image]

Paste the values from column `C` into Notepad++, then use Replace to change `;` to a carriage return using the Regex `\r\n` (make sure Search Mode includes the `Extended` option)

[image]

This then results in a list which meets your expected output format

[image]

Comment: Perfect - this is exactly what i did. Thank you for taking the time to respond @spikey_richie !!

Comment: You're must welcome.